# Как считывать несколько чисел в одной строке, когда количество чисел в строке с каждым разом увеличивается на 1 на Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я написал код для решения олимпиадной задачи на языке Python 3.7 с данным условием:

> Вася коллекционирует карточки «Клуб Винкс», сейчас в его коллекции уже n разных карточек. Каждая карточка из набора имеет уникальный номер от 1 до 100. Вася любит порядок, поэтому каждый раз, когда в его коллекции появлялась новая карточка, он добавлял ее в коллекцию, после чего упорядочивал все карточки по возрастанию номеров, и фотографировал свою коллекцию на память.

> Недавно Васе стало интересно, какие карточки в его коллекции уже давно, а какие появились недавно. К сожалению, он уже забыл, в каком порядке карточки появлялись в его коллекции, но у него остались фотографии коллекции после добавления каждой новой карточки. Помогите ему по этим фотографиям восстановить порядок, в котором карточки появлялись в коллекции.

Входные данные:

> Первая строка содержит целое число n (1≤n≤100).

> Следующие n строк содержат описание коллекции после добавления очередной карточки, k-е из этих описаний содержит k целых чисел — список номеров карточек, отсортированный по возрастанию. Все номера — это целые числа от 1 до 100. Гарантируется, что все карточки в коллекции имеют различные номера.

Выходные данные

> выведите n чисел — номера карточек в том порядке, в котором они появлялись в коллекции Васи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я написал этот код

```
val = int(input())
blist = []
for i in range(val):
    for j in range(i+1):
        x = int(input())
        if blist.count(x) == 0:
            blist.append(x)
print(blist)
```

`val` - кол-во фотографий
`blist` - список, куда добавляются карточки в порядке появления в коллекции.

```
    if blist.count(x) == 0:
        blist.append(x)
```

Этой строкой я исключаю повторения карточек в списке

Я столкнулся с проблемой. Данная программа работает при вводе чисел данным путём:

- 5
- 4
- 4
- 9
- 2
- 4
- 9

и т д

Но ввод должен осуществляться вот так:

- 5
- 4
- 49
- 249
- 2479

Я понял, что дело в том, что в строке может быть несколько чисел, и с каждой фотографией количество чисел в одной строке становится больше на 1.
Вопрос:
Как считывать несколько чисел в одной строке, когда количество чисел в строке с каждым разом увеличивается на 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
blist = [] 
for i in range(val):
    x = input().split()
    blist.append(list(map(int, x)))
```

с помощью `split` разделяем строку по пробелу. с помощью `map` переводим в `int` каждый элемент списка

Comment: большое Вам спасибо!